# The repository is in queue for creation (Issue?) Tuleap

Tags: tuleap

The repository never gets created in project under git, in admin panel it shows ok. i can initialize repo and push to it. But it never shows up, i have reinstalled fresh tuleap few times that did not fix it.

The repository is in queue for creation. Please check back here in a few minutes

https://tuleap.net/plugins/forumml/message.php?group_id=101&topic=28722&list=1

i believe my issue is related to this mans problem, but hes unclear to how exactly did he fix it any idea?

Can tuleap once installing is not set correctly on git side and does not work out of the box? I tried re installing couple of latest different version on different servers and it just does not work.

Comment: What do you mean, "i can initialize repo and push to it"? Do you mean you can initialize a repo outside of Tuleap, or is the repo correctly created but just doesn't appear in Tuleap?

Comment: in admin panel it shows that "SystemEvent_GIT_REPO_UPDATE OK" so the repo is created fine, but does not appear in tuleap. I meant that I was able to initialize and push to the repository in terminal.

Comment: Did you try the different commands suggested in the mail list you linked?

-> Check if codendiadm is member of gitolite group: `id codendiadm`

-> Log as codendiadm (`su codendiadm`) and issue a `git status` in /var/lib/codendi/gitolite/admin. You should see a list of your different operation. If it says "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by XX commits." then you may have a persmission issue